# PHP get data from database and put the data into a string

Tags: php, sql

I am still new to PHP. I have tried a few stuff, but I just can't get it to work.

**Question:** I want all the data from my `users` table to be in a string, separated by comma. Then when the `ID` is `2` to be `;` for net new row, so on and so forth. If someone can please help me.

```
$server = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "users";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user_name, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users;";
$result = $conn ->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $rows = implode (";",$result);
    $array = $rows;

    echo $array;
}
```

**Question2:** But if I want first row of DB data to be, separated and then at the end with a `;`. How would I do that?

**Output:** The output of this code is:
`Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your user table has 2 fields **Firstname and Lastname**. What I understood  from your question is you want your output to be something like

```
$array = ['steve,jobs;', 'mark,zukerberg;'];
```

To achieve this you can append *';'* at the end of the string.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
     $rows = implode(',',$row) . ';'; //you have named this variable $rows but it is going to have data of a single row
     $array = $rows; //you could directly var_dump($rows) instead of assigning it to a new variable
     echo $array; //you could rather use var_dump($array) for this
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted. sorry if i structured my question wrong. Still new to the php stuff

Answer (score 2):

You've simply used the wrong variable in your call to `ìmplode`.

You've assigned all the columns as an array to `$row` - but you're trying to implode `$result`.

Update that line to this:

`$rows = implode(";", $row);`

Comment: But if i want first row of `DB` data to be `,` separated and then at the end with a `;` How would i do that?